# Moon's revolution around the Earth and it's rotation around it's axis?

Tags: the-moon, rotation

Does Moon rotate around itself while it makes one revolution around Earth or not?

Comment: Yes it does! The linked "duplicate" question has several answers that address this. It's not a bad thing if your question is marked as duplicate, it helps readers find those answers. Feel free to ask another question, or if you want you can modify your question so that what's asked is not answered there.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Exactly once. This is how we get the light and dark side of the moon. The reason for it being exactly once is due to something called tidal forces. Wikipedia explains this quite well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking.

Comment: 'light' and 'dark' are ambiguous, it's better to call them the 'near' and 'far' side of the Moon.

Comment: @Hobbes, if we are knit-picking, technically not so. Near and far are necessarily subjective, the light side absolutely receives more light due to earth-shine. If we are not then I think both are acceptable.

Comment: near and far are unambiguous to anyone on Earth. Light and dark always lead to discussions about the dark side not really being dark, etc.

Comment: @ANone _If_ one side does receive more light due to Earth-shine, how much more light and what is your source?

Comment: @Mick enough that on earth you can see the reflected earth-light as it in turn is reflected off the moon.

Comment: No they really aren't "both acceptable". The "Dark Side of the Moon" is an album by Pink Floyd, but it's not a reference to a fixed side of the Moon. The side of the Moon that is dark is always moving, and it's better to refer to it as the night side. The comments are meant to be helpful, not critical. Stack Exchange is (ideally) a bit of a "team effort" and the goal is to generate the best answers. I think in this case it's better if you fix the problematic use of "dark side" to something more scientifically accurate.